# How can I override built in Flutter Widget's functions?

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, overriding

I want to change just a few lines of code in tabs.dart file:

```
void _handleTap(int index) {
   assert(index >= 0 && index < widget.tabs.length);
   _controller!.animateTo(index);
   widget.onTap?.call(index);
}
```

I want to change this function with a custom function. Should I duplicate the whole tab.dart file and create my own modified tab widget or is there a simple way to override this?

I want to call the Tab widget as usual but when _handeTap method is called, I want it to behave different and call another function and never run whats insinde the original method.

Answer (score 0):

You tecnically can just override the method creating another class CustomTab and overriding that method, but i dont't think it's good practice.
Now, i don't know what you wanna do, but why you can't just use `onTap:` parameter in the TabBar?
Or, maybe wrapping the `Tab` in a `GestureDetector` and giving the `onTap:` parameter should work to do what you want.
But again, i didn't understand what you want to do, so i cannot help you further.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that approach with GestureDetector. The reason I can't use onTap event is it will do the things I put in the event AFTER it changes the tab. I want to validate some variables and then if everything is ok, it will change the tab. If not, it do other things WITHOUT changing the tab. I thought about checking after the tab change and if it shouldn't, it would just go back to the previous tab but it is hard because there are a lot of things going on with every tab change so my first intention is to completely block the tab change.